# How to edit the values in one column when a certain value is realised in another in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have the following DataFrame with several columns beyond the ones included here:

```
    Col2      Col3    Col4
0   3682   US91892      US
1   7568   US91234      US
2   3546     UKIPD      GB
3   7892     UKI43      GB
4   1243   US92345      US
```

For this if col4 = US I want to get only the the last 5 digits for col3 such as:

```
    Col2      Col3    Col4
0   3682     91892      US
1   7568     91234      US
2   3546     UKIPD      GB
3   7892     UKI43      GB
4   1243     92345      US
```

For this I have tried:

```
for a in df.index:
    if df["col4"][a] == "US":
        df["col3"][a] = df["col3"][a][-5:]
```

However, it is taking several hours to run (the dataset is around 170,000 datapoints with several of such datasets). I was wondering whether there was a quicker and more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df.Col4=='US', 'Col3'] = df.Col3.str[-5:]
```

Output:

```
   Col2   Col3 Col4
0  3682  91892   US
1  7568  91234   US
2  3546  UKIPD   GB
3  7892  UKI43   GB
4  1243  92345   US
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Also works very fast and efficiently

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df['Col3'] = df['Col3'].str[-5:].where(df['Col4'].eq('US'),df['Col3'])
#or df['Col3'] = np.where(df['Col4'].eq('US'),df['Col3'].str[-5:],df['Col3'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   Col2   Col3 Col4
0  3682  91892   US
1  7568  91234   US
2  3546  UKIPD   GB
3  7892  UKI43   GB
4  1243  92345   US
```

Comment: This is great thank you! It ran in close to a second rather than an hour